# Download image using PHP but image is htaccess redirected?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, curl

I want to download an image to my server using PHP.  This image's html only allows target="_self" meaning it can only be downloaded from the browser apparently. I try to access the image directly in the browser and I get redirected.  Is there any way to download this image onto my server via PHP?  Maybe I'm missing an option in cURL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to tell CURL to follow redirects --- try this function:

```
function wgetImg($img, $pathToSaveTo) {
    $ch = curl_init($img);
    $fp = fopen($pathToSaveTo, 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work.  It produces the same results as just regular copy();

Comment: Well, that really should work - Can you post the images' HTML for an example?